# How to scroll down then go up using nested loop - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to avoid using element id to click on button so all I need is to scroll down then I click on the button but sometime the page has different hight and I want to avoid that as well ..
The correct hight is about 1200 Y down but as I said some of pages has different hight and 1200 y is not going to help to click the button,
Here is what I did:

```
window.scrollTo(0,1600);

do{
window.scrollBy(0, -700);
document.getElementsByClassName('button1')[5].click();
i=undefined
}while(i !=undefined);
```

But I don't know if I can use nested loop to scroll to the bottom of the page then to go up let say 700 so I can click the button

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to scroll to click a `button`?

Comment: also that looks like an endless loop

Comment: To go to the next page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folks I've figured it out, all we need is to use "**await**" after scrolling down and before scrolling up:

```
do{
window.scroll({
    top: 2000
  })
 await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 100));
  window.scroll({
    top: -2000
  })
  document.getElementsByClassName('button1')[5].click();
  i=undefined
  }while(i !=undefined);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to it with `scrollBy()`. Just pass the id of the target location in `window.location.href`.

make sure you add `scroll-behavior: smooth;` otherwise it just snap to the bottom.

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

div {
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<button onclick="window.location.href = '#footer'">
        scroll to footer
    </button>
<div></div>
<h1 id="footer">footer</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you Umair but I don't want to use a button to go down or up.